# KeyError while mapping values with python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I'm using python to replaces codes with string:

```
decoding_dict = {'A1A': 'blue', 'ZA3': 'GREEN', 'M9': 'HIGH'}
```

I have a list of list with those codes:

```
codes_list = [['A1A'], ['ZA3', 'M9'], ['A6A']]
```

If that case for example, the code in the third list isn't defined in the dictionary, so if I try:

```
decoding_dict[ codes_list[2][0] ]
```

I will get a `KeyError` exception, if instead of that I use:

```
decoding_dict.get(codes_list[2][0] )
```

I wouldn't get an error but I will return a none value, since I'm appending the results in other list I end up having something like this:

```
['blue', None, 'HIGH', 'GREEN', None, 'GREEN']
```

what's the correct way of handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test for the key first:

```
if codes_list[2][0] in decoding_dict:
    # do something with decoding_dict[codes_list[2][0]]
```

You could produce your output using a list comprehension with that filter:

```
[decoding_dict[v] for sublist in codes_list for v in sublist if v in decoding_dict]
```